# American megatrends logo is displayed between plymouth end and lightdm start

Tags: boot, lightdm, startx, plymouth

In order to create an home made kiosk system I installed Ubuntu 20.04 Server. I configured plymouth to display my custom theme and set up the auto login using LightDM. After the auto-login is complete openbox will start and consequently chromium will be started.

My issue is that between the end of plymouth and the X start by LightDM, the "American Megatrend" logo is displayed again. It is not a big issue but it's quite annoying.

here my lightdm.conf

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=kuser
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=openbox
xserver-command=X -bs -core -nocursor
```

and my grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet"
```

thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Do you mean the BIOS logo? If you don't want to see it for second time (whatever the reason for that is), then probably you won't miss it if you don't see it fo the first time too. Have you tried disabling it from the menu?

Comment: yes is the BIOS logo. Unfortunately there isn't an option for hide the logo into the bios. I'm using an hold cherry-trail embedded board I had recover...

Answer (score 1):

Try the kernel option "fbcon=nodefer" to disable the deferred fbcon takeover support.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the problem. I just edited /etc/default/grub adding that parameter in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and now the AM logo is not displayed again